# Toggle() an element by class name within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a javascript/jquery function that looks inside a div with a specific ID and removes a specific class from any child div(s) with a specific class.

E.g. the function should remove the class `removeme` from any divs inside `div id="foo"`:

```
<div id="foo" onClick="openGame('foo')">
    <div class="bar removeme"></div>
</div>
```

My attempt at writing this function:

```
function openGame(divid) {
    var container = document.getElementById(divid);
    var responses = container.getElementsByClassName("bar");
    while (responses[0]) {
        responses[0].removeClass('removeme');
    };
}
```

Please note I'm a super beginner in JS and not super familiar with while loops :/

Comment: I would use `responses.forEach( funcion( el ) { el.removeClass('removeme') });`

Comment: Are you using jQuery?  Your tag suggests so, but your code does not.

Comment: You want this: http://jsfiddle.net/0tc14qj1/

Comment: @JoshCrozier Yes, that's what I wanted! Thanks a million!

Comment: @Sahadeva You're welcome. `.removeClass` is a jQuery method. You therefore had to wrap `responses[0]` with `$()` and ditch the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jQuery to achieve this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div#foo').click(function() {
        $(this).find('.removeme').removeClass('removeme');
    });
});
```

This creates a click event on your element with the id "foo" that will find every elements inside of it and remove the class "removeme" from it.

Comment: He wants to remove the class, not the element from the dom.

Answer (score 1):

I would use JQuery for this job:

```
$("#foo").find("div").removeClass("removeme");
```

This will find all children of #foo and remove the class `.removeme`.

Comment: @canon Neither does your answer. The OP wants to target child elements with class `bar`.

Comment: @canon "*removes a specific class from any child div(s) with a specific class*"

Comment: `removeme` was indeed the specific class in the OP's code.

Comment: @canon Judging by `container.getElementsByClassName("bar");`, the OP was targeting the `.bar` elements.

Comment: At any rate the OP now has 3 examples upon which he can build